# Next.js build loads for a split second but disappears but works fine in dev

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, server-side-rendering

My next.js project with typescript works just fine in dev however, when the built `npm run build`' the page loads and disappears. I think it has something to do with layout page however, I'm not sure. I've gotten the following in console.

Uncaught Error: Minified React error #418; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=418 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
Uncaught Error: Minified React error #423; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=423 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': Only one element on document allowed.
DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.

**layout.tsx**

```
import './globals.css'
import type { Metadata } from 'next'
// import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar'
import Image from 'next/image'
// const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'redacted',
  description: 'Personal Website',
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <div className="relative">
      <div className="-z-1 bg-night absolute inset-0">
        <div className="fixed w-screen h-screen pointer-events-none bg-scroll">
          <Image src="/bg-circle.png" alt={''} layout="fill" objectFit="cover" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className='flex justify-center'>
        <div className="fixed z-10 w-2/5">
          <Navbar />
        </div>
      </div>

      
      <div className="relative z-0">{children}</div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I've tried editing the {children} props component part however nothing seems to work.